# how to click a button as long as xpath is not found on web browser using python? i don't want to use sleep function

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a program in python using web browser. There is an internet issue. When the internet is slow, the program gets the error (`xpath is not found`) and stops. I am also using the `sleep` function

How can I create a `while` loop of xpath?
or any other methods please explain.

I have done this...

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span').click()
time.sleep(3)
```

**i want to do**

when internet gets slow. The program will wait for xpath then click.

Comment: Share this HTML `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span` first

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Explicit Wait`

See this link : https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use webdriver wait.
It was introduced exactly for this purpose.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span'))).click()
```

You also should use better locators.
`//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span`
doesn't look good at all.

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
what is 20 in it.

Comment: It is the timeout in seconds. Selenium will try to find element matching the passed locator, here `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span` up to 20 seconds. Once the element is found to be visible, the click on it will be performed. In case element was not found in 20 seconds exception will be thrown.

Comment: @OmkarNath BTW I see you didn't ever accept any answer to your questions. It's not a good manner...

Comment: You are welcome. In case i answered your question please accept my answer

Comment: i am just created my account on this website few days ago. i don't known how to handle it.